# Need some help to understand this VBA FOR NEXT LOOP?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need some help to understand this vba MACRO that create 28 Pivot Tables. the macro creates the pivotTables in two columns, the line of code that make it posible and

> I do not understand is : *For Col = 1 To 6 Step 5 '2 columns*.

I am posting all the code

```
Sub MakePivotTables()

    Dim PTCache As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim ItemName As String
    Dim Row As Long, Col As Long, i As Long

Set SummarySheet = Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary"
    

    Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
      SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
      SourceData:=Sheets("SurveyData").Range("A1"). _
        CurrentRegion)
    
    Row = 1
    For i = 1 To 14
      *For Col = 1 To 6 Step 5 '2 columns*
        ItemName = Sheets("SurveyData").Cells(1, i + 2)
        With Cells(Row, Col)
            .Value = ItemName
            .Font.Size = 16
        End With


        Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add( _
          PivotCache:=PTCache, _
          TableDestination:=SummarySheet.Cells(Row + 1, Col))
        

        If Col = 1 Then 'Frequency tables
            With pt.PivotFields(ItemName)
              .Orientation = xlDataField
              .Name = "Frequency"
              .Function = xlCount
            End With
        Else ' Percent tables
        With pt.PivotFields(ItemName)
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Name = "Percent"
            .Function = xlCount
            .Calculation = xlPercentOfColumn
            .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        End With
        End If
   
        pt.PivotFields(ItemName).Orientation = xlRowField
        pt.PivotFields("Sex").Orientation = xlColumnField
        pt.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium2"
        pt.DisplayFieldCaptions = False
        If Col = 6 Then

            pt.ColumnGrand = False
            pt.DataBodyRange.Columns(3).FormatConditions. _
            AddDatabar
            With pt.DataBodyRange.Columns(3).FormatConditions(1)
                .BarFillType = xlDataBarFillSolid
                .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=0
                .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=1
            End With
        End If
     Next Col
        Row = Row + 10
   Next i
   

    With Range("A:A,F:F")
        .Replace "1", "Strongly Disagree"
        .Replace "2", "Disagree"
        .Replace "3", "Undecided"
        .Replace "4", "Agree"
        .Replace "5", "Strongly Agree"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: On the first loop iteration, `Col` is equal to `1`. Then, on the next loop iteration, it *steps* 5 forward and is equal to 6. The loop only runs twice, once with `Col=1` and once with `Col=6`, which is what the comment is trying to say.

Comment: That's clever if you want column A and F without having to do math.

Comment: its clever but does make the code a little tricky to read!  is nice though because other you end up with the Col + (Col - 1) * 5 similar to which I have used a lot!

Comment: @InjuredCoding that kind of math is how one gets in trouble @_@

Comment: @findwindow well indeed but honestly I think that step is more confusing to me and luckily I have a degree in the maths (ironic as I just noticed inmy example it would by *4 to get to the outcome of the if statement!  - i'm going for that code was never going to be used and its late!)

Comment: Thanks Toddleson for the answer, for me that part of the code is difficult to read!

Comment: Strangest part to me is that Row variable just above it could also have been written `For Row=1 to 141 Step 10`, but wasn't.  Why do one but not the other?